# Tool for improving old recordings

Tags: effects, mastering, compression, 4-track

I'm looking for a tool like this, but not quite sure what to call it. I have a number of MP3s of recordings I did on 4-track tape back in the day. I quite like them but the recording is fairly poor and lacking in bass etc.

I also use FL Studio, in which I have an effect called Soundgoodizer, which just seems to be some presets of http://flstudio.image-line.com/help/html/plugins/Maximus.htm. It doesn't really have any controls but adds a lot of oomph and crispness to the sounds.

What I'm looking for is something similar that I can run my mp3s through. I don't really want to have to convert them all into WAV files, import them into FL Studio as audio tracks (some of them are around 40 minutes long) and then export the whole thing again. There must be something that will just import an MP3 directly, equalize, compress and do whatever else the Soundgoodizer does (with sensible presets but the option to tweak), and then save it as a new mp3?

Comment: what OS? (you mentioned WAV, I suppose windows?), also to do that I suppose you will need a raw file (WAV, AIFF, ...), so the software you are looking for may do the conversion for you to a raw format automatically and probably then convert back to MP3 as you said, but, knowing this, you could already convert all MP3 to WAV and use a solution you know works well already. May take time, but IMO excellence takes time :) - FInally, I have no suggestions for a software that can do that automatically.

Comment: Windows or Linux. But I'm thinking I'm more likely to find this on Windows.

Sure, I know excellence takes time, but I see no reason for it to take unnecessary work when a program is as capable of converting an MP3 file to an uncompressed audio format as I am :-)

Comment: BTW : I have over 10 hours (and 100+ tunes) of this stuff. Hence why I'm keen to find a program to automate the unnecessary extras. It's not just laziness.

Answer (score 1):

The way mp3's are encoded and compressed doesn't lend itself well to this at all, so you need to convert to wav anyway. The way I would do it is to script up the following:

convert mp3 to wav
pipe wav into FL studio
run the plugin
export as mp3

(if the FL studio steps can be scripted too, all the better, but I don't know the app)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think FL Studio is scriptable, and frankly, it seems like overkill to have to import a large audio file into a multi-track DAW just to run it through one filter.